# How to store profile image to firebase programatically swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimageview, firebase-storage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having trouble storing my image to firebase to then have it set as the user profile image, can anyone help? for some reason, it's not storing on firebase?

CODE:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if  let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.image = originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    } else if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.image = editedImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)


    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    guard let image = self.changeButton.imageView?.image else { return }
    guard let uploadDate = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else  { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

    storageRef.putData(uploadDate, metadata: nil, completion:  { (metadata, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to upload", err)
            return
        }
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(downloadURL, err) in

            guard let profileImageURL = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }

            print("Successfully uploaded profile image", profileImageURL)
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: Explain the trouble you're facing.

Comment: It’s not storing the firebase

Comment: What's the output you're getting in the console? Add this to your question.

Comment: I’m getting no output